# AttributeError: module 'torch.distributed' has no attribute 'is_initialized' in pytorch==1.11.X

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

**whenever we are creating the object for TrainingArguments**

```
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments
batch_size = 64
logging_steps = len(emotions_encoded["train"]) // batch_size
model_name = f"{model_ckpt}-finetuned-emotion"
training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir=model_name,
                                      num_train_epochs=2,
                                      learning_rate=2e-5,
                                      per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
                                      per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
                                      weight_decay=0.01,
                                      evaluation_strategy="epoch",
                                      disable_tqdm=False,
                                      logging_steps=logging_steps,
                                      push_to_hub=True,
                                      log_level="error")
```

I am getting

AttributeError: module 'torch.distributed' has no attribute 'is_initialized'

Comment: upvoted to bring it back to zero :) since finding this helped me over a hurdle.

Answer (score 2):

In order to solve this problem

Actually Window and Mac doesn't support distributed training facility

so this issue is occuring

To solve this problem

go to your transformers package where you install it

in my case it is

```
Desktop/rajesh/pytorch_env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/training_args.py
```

replace line-1024
if torch.distributed.is_initialized() and self.local_rank == -1:
with
if True and self.local_rank == -1:

Restart your kernal

Comment: it stings to upvote such a deep hack for a downvoted question, but this got me past a similar problem while following a tutorial on my mac that had originally been run in collab - hence linux. (I had to fix model_utils.py, not training_args.py) and the cause is truly a bug in torch, not a problem with library versions, which were all in sync. See: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/module-torch-distributed-has-no-attribute-is-initialized/55391

Comment: Another temporary fix is to use monkey-patching, i.e.
`setattr(torch.distributed, "is_initialized", lambda : False)`